# Specifying order of resources

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, resources

I'm trying to add a path to my application.  I have code that functions as I'd like, but I'd like to group it differently so that it's more intuitive to read.  Here's the code:

```
get 'posts/search' => 'posts#search',
  :as => :search_posts

put 'posts/search_result' => 'posts#search_result',
  :as => :search_posts_result

resources :posts do

end
```

but I'd like to do something like this:

```
resources :posts do
  get 'posts/search' => 'posts#search',
    :as => :search_posts

  put 'posts/search_result' => 'posts#search_result',
    :as => :search_posts_result
end
```

It's a really small difference, but doing it the latter way defines runs `resources :posts` first.  As a result, Rails tries to match `/posts/search` to `/posts/:id` (for show) and gives an error as it can't find a post with id 'search'.  Is there a way I can tell rails to run the get and put definitions before running `resources :posts`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason your routes aren't working is because they are defined on each member of posts, so `/posts/1/posts/search`. You should run `rake routes` to check where your routes are going.

To fix your problem, you would probably want to fix those route paths and make sure you're defining the search route on the entire collection. If this is confusing, check the [guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html).

```
resources :posts do
  get :search, :on => :collection
end
```

You don't need all that other stuff you had, either. This will create all of the following routes for you:

```
search_posts GET    /posts/search(.:format)    {:action=>"search", :controller=>"posts"}
       posts GET    /posts(.:format)           {:action=>"index", :controller=>"posts"}
             POST   /posts(.:format)           {:action=>"create", :controller=>"posts"}
    new_post GET    /posts/new(.:format)       {:action=>"new", :controller=>"posts"}
   edit_post GET    /posts/:id/edit(.:format)  {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"posts"}
        post GET    /posts/:id(.:format)       {:action=>"show", :controller=>"posts"}
             PUT    /posts/:id(.:format)       {:action=>"update", :controller=>"posts"}
             DELETE /posts/:id(.:format)       {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"posts"}
```

Rails defines the routes on the entire collection before the default resourceful routes (as you can see above) so that your routes take precedence.

And as far as your `PUT posts#search_result` method, well, that's really confusing — you want to update a search result manually?

---

*Per the comments:* I'd recommend something like this instead of having a separate action for search results. Typically a search page looks the same with or without results, except the error message if you do a search and nothing turns up. Gracefully handling the case that a search page is shown without a query being present lets you nix a redundant action.

```
def search
  @query == params[:q] || ''

  # search logic

  flash[:error] = 'Nothing found message' if @results.empty? unless @query.blank?
end
```

Comment: You're right about using `PUT posts#search_result`.  I realized after writing this that it should be a `GET`.  Thanks for the thoughtful answer.  Both your answer and dinatih's worked, but I'm giving this one to you for the extra description.

Comment: @Eric Hu: Thanks for the accept. Color me stupid, but shouldn't a search result for /posts/search be a post itself, not a separate type? In other words, shouldn't the link for each search result be a /post/id?

Comment: Thank you for the answer!  As I currently have it planned out, `posts#search_results` (I added an s in my code) is like `posts#index`, but lists only posts relevant to the user's search params entered in `posts#search`.  For the time being, it actually uses the `posts#index` view, but I anticipate making a separate view for `posts#search_results` so that it can be done with AJAX.  Does that make sense?

Comment: Isn't that the same page as `GET posts#search`? Are you redirecting from `search` to `search_results`?

Comment: yes, at the moment `search` is just a form for entering search params.  Perhaps it's not necessary if I don't require any advanced search options.

Comment: I updated my answer to include a snippet that might help you with that.

Comment: I'd just like to add that the flash error persists for 2 searches this way.  For anyone who wants to use this as a solution, change the flash notification to `flash.now[:error] = 'Nothing found message'`

Comment: Really? It shouldn't. Perhaps something else is interfering?

Comment: I wasn't able to figure it out yesterday, but I now see why it's behaving this way.  A flash notification persists to the end of the next controller action.  Here's what's happening:

`Action 1`: Load search page, user searches for invalid string
`Action 2`: search field processed, flash is set.  Search page is rendered.  The flash is displayed here, but this is considered the same action.
`Action 3`: valid search field processed.  The flash expires here since it was set in action 2, but not before the view is rendered and re-displays the same flash.

Comment: 2 consecutive invalid searches will behave as expected.  This only happens with an invalid followed by a valid search (0 results, 1+ results)

Answer (score 1):

```
resources :posts do
  collection do
    get :search, :as => :search_posts
    put :search_result, :as => :search_posts_result
  end 
end
```

Comment: Ah, this worked.  Thanks!  I tried doing this earlier but forgot to change 'posts/search' to just 'search'.

Comment: ;), So can you validate my answer please.

Comment: :P I had a hard time choosing between your answer and coreyward's since they both work.  Yours was 2 minutes earlier but I felt his post explained a little more.  I gave you an upvote as thanks for your answer though.  Sorry, I'd mark them both right if I could!